# Enviar e-mail HTML com formatação em Android (style inline)

Tags: android, email, envio-de-email

Estou tentando enviar um e-mail personalizado através de [`new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127676/how-to-send-html-mail-in-android), contendo no corpo de e-mail um HTML formatado, mas ao selecionar o aplicativo do Gmail, por exemplo, todo o `style` do html é ignorado. O que estou tentando é o seguinte:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/html");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"destino@mail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<h1>Sou um H1</h1><p>Eu sou um paragrafo</p><p style=\"color:red;background-color:black;\">Eu sou um paragrafo colorido!</p>"));
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

O aplicativo de e-mail é chamado corretamente, mas a parte do `style` do HTML é perdida. **É possível manter o HTML intacto nessa forma de enviar e-mail através de `Intent.ACTION_SEND`?**

Answer (score 1):

Basta utilizar o parâmetro Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT

```
i.sendIntent.setType(“text/html”);

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<h1>Sou um H1</h1><p>Eu sou um paragrafo</p><p style=\"color:red;background-color:black;\">Eu sou um paragrafo colorido!</p>").toString());
```

OU

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, "<h1>Sou um H1</h1><p>Eu sou um paragrafo</p><p style=\"color:red;background-color:black;\">Eu sou um paragrafo colorido!</p>");
```

Comment: Isso funcionou para você? Pois testei aqui e não funcionou! Se seto somente o `Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT` como você sugeriu, da a seguinte alerta no console: `Key android.intent.extra.HTML_TEXT expected String but value was a android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.  The default value <null> was returned`. e não aparece nada no corpo do e-mail. Se seto também o `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` ele aparece somente o conteúdo do `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` no corpo do e-mail e não o do `Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT`. Estou testando no Android 5.0, e selecionando o gerenciador de e-mail do Gmail.

Comment: Desculpa, existem duas formas. Vou alterar as possibilidades, caso não funcione com você, eu removo a resposta.